Is it legal to rename/fork an existing Linux distro for commercial use?
Suppose I take a parent distribution (slackware for example), take its packages and package management scripts, rename the scripts and the packages in a minor way (without changing the verbatim copyright work), add a few scripts/work of my own (no proprietary stuff), thus creating a Linux distro of my own from it, call it abclinux, and then sell the service on it to some people for money.
Is this process valid/legal?
I ask this because AFAIK, GNU GPL licenses and other copyleft permissible licenses give you the freedom to modify the work and charge for the service (as long as you maintain the attribution to the author/creator of the work).
So is this whole process legal?
I mean Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian after all, right?

Have you read the license files governing the distributions (not all of it is GPL)? What is the basis for your doubts? Before you start the work you can check if there is an existing distribution which already does what you try to achieve.

Yes, (re-)selling of open-source products (applications, distro's, etc.) for monetary gain is fully allowed. It is even a requirement for open-source licenses that they cannot forbid such commercial exploitation of the code.
What some licenses forbid is asking additional money (any, or an amount larger than shipping costs) for providing the source code. This is to prevent tricks like making the binary available for free and asking $1 mln of those who want the source code to exercise the rights they received with the open-source license.
Where a business model based on selling copies of open-source code usually breaks down is that each customer is allowed to re-sell additional copies and they can undercut your price that way, even down to providing it for free.

Not just re-sell but to put the entire distribution, binaries + source, on a public site for anybody to download for free.

Note that this answer, though excellent, doesn't deal with trademark licensing.  With certain pieces of software it may be mandatory to change the name (and associated branding) on redistribution, and with others, on non-verbatim redistribution.  As Martin notes above, there is no substitute for actually reading all the relevant licences.
